# reinterpret_cast rvalue using some reference

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How does one do a *direct* `reinterpret_cast` for a temporary/rvalue? Consider the following example:

```
struct s
{
    void f( )
    { }
};

auto m = &s::f;
auto p = reinterpret_cast< void * & >( m );
// works: ref cast (also, c-style ptr casting)

union u
{
    decltype( &s::f ) o;
    void * c;
};
auto pr2 = u { &s::f }.c;
// works: type punning

auto pr = reinterpret_cast< void * magic_ref >( &s::f );
// nothing to do this
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215870/discussion-on-question-by-super-developer-reinterpret-cast-rvalue-using-some-ref).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you just want

```
void* pr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(&s::f);
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3559c07a34cec699)

but `void*` and member function pointers are [incompatible](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#cant-cvt-memfnptr-to-voidptr).

Comment: This will not compile. You would need to do something like `*(void**)&var` or `(void*&)var`

Comment: @superdeveloper [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/u2_Tf_) but with warnings.

Comment: @superdeveloper: it is the conversion which is invalid `void*` and member pointer functions are not compatible, you just have workaround to silent the diagnostic.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.